# How can I pass JS variable to PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php

First i have to say that I'm new to programming.

I have **index.html** where var id is generated

```
var id = feature.properties.id;

                                          $.ajax({
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            url: 'id.php',
                                            dataType: 'json',
                                            data: {'id': id},
                                            success: function (data)
                                            {
                                              console.log(data);
                                            }
```

And I want to use that var (id) to create a sql query in **id.php**

```
$y = $_GET['id'];

if (isset($y))
{
    $x = 'SELECT * FROM info WHERE id=' . $y;
}

# Try query or error
$rs = $conn->query($x);
if (!$rs) {
    echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
    exit;
}
```

These are the errors that I am getting. Any help?

> Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\asc\maps\leaflet\id.php
> on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: x in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\asc\maps\leaflet\id.php on line 13 An SQL error
> occured.\n

Comment: You can inject value to hidden input through js and receive it on php file on submit form

Comment: Shouldn't be trying to access database if the data doesn't validate either

Comment: I tried changing it to $_POST but i get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

the thing is that you're doing a POST in jQuery so in PHP you should do:
`$y = $_POST['id'];`
that way it will work, also you should make sure that `id` in jQuery has a value;

Comment: Explaining the difference between `GET` and `POST` methods (with examples) would be nice. As the OP said, they're new to programming and this is useful knowledge.

Comment: use: `$.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
              url: 'id.php',
              data: {'id': id},
               success: function (data)
                {
                       console.log(data);
                 } })`   note that I removed: `dataType: 'json',` from the ajax request

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\asc\maps\leaflet\id.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined variable: x in D:\xampp\htdocs\asc\maps\leaflet\id.php on line 13 An SQL error occured.\n

Comment: did you removed `dataType: 'json',` from the ajax request ?

Comment: it worked by putting everything inside of if(isset($_POST["id"]))

Comment: good to know !, make sure to mark as help full my response, if it really helped you.